# Can I store a long value precisely in a double variable without any rounding error?

Tags: java

I have written a converter which uses Double.parseDouble to convert string to long value. Because user some times give input in xx.xx format instead of pure integer format. Is there any possibility to lose information when parsing a long value using Double.parseDouble?

```
static Long toLong(Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (object instanceof Number) {
        return ((Number) object).longValue();
    }
    return new Double(Double.parseDouble(object.toString().trim())).longValue();
}
```

Comment: Why not try it? Enter a long string and see what happens. That way you can also see, how much information gets lost..

Comment: Yes, there is. Both use 64 bits. But Double needs to be able to store decimals, whereas Long doesn't. So obviously, Double can't store as many precise integer values as long does.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.
A `double` uses just 53 bits to store the *mantissa* – the actual digits in the number.
The other 11 bits are used to store the *exponent* – where the decimal is.

Therefore, you cannot precisely express 64 bits of digits in a `double`.

Comment: nitpick, but: "the exponent – where the decimal is" - due to the binary representation, the exponent indicates where the binary point is, not the decimal point.

Comment: The "Yes" in this answer is actually answering the question in the description ("Is there any possibility to lose information...?") and not the question in the title ("Can I store a long value precisely...?"). Confused me a bit on first sight.